# How to conform both to MKAnnotation and Codable?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, swift5, codable

I want to present one of my object on a map. So, at the class declaration, i made it conform to `MKAnnotation`. Conforming to MKAnnotation requires me to add a coordinate property of type CLLocationCoordinate2D. But I want to be able to send those object to a webserver later, so my object need to conform to either NSSecureCoding or Codable. Since i want to user JSONEncoder and JSONdecoder, then i want to go for Codable instead. When implementing the class declaration, Xcode lets me know that `CLLocationCoodinate2D` doesnt not conform to Codable. Searching on the web, I found a solution, to make the class conform to Codable, by declaring a type wrapper (I will show the code), **But even though this solves the Codable issue, I can't make the class conform to MKAnnotation.**

```
    class SomeClass: NSObject, MKAnnotation, Codable {
var property1: String
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D //required for conformance to MKAnnotation
var image: Image //another property that would not conform to Coadable, but i could make it using a type wrapper.
}
struct Image: Codable {
let imageData: Data? 
init(with image: UIImage) {
self.imageData = image.png()
}
public func getImage()-> UIImage? {
guard let imageData = self.imageData, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {return nil}
return image
}
```

**If I use the same solution with coordinate property, the would change, and then I no longer conform to `MKAnnotation`.**

Comment: You will need to use a `CodingKeys` enumeration to exclude the `coordinate` property and add additional properties to represent the latitude and longitude values

Comment: What is the actual JSON supposed to look like? You have a number of options once you incorporate coding keys and custom encode(to:) and init(from:) methods.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488292/custom-class-conformance-to-mkannotation-and-codable/61491122#61491122 for example.